# Regex select between two "strings"

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of files that when someone launches the program it will get the "normal Files" and when someone does a Full Check, it will get the "Full Check Files".

```
[normalFiles]
element\userdata\systemsettings.ini
element\userdata\server\serverlist.txt
element\data\elements.data
element\data\gshop.data
element\data\gshop1.data
element\data\gshop2.data
element\elementskill.dll
element\configs.pck
element\monkeydynasty.exe
element\data\aipolicy.data
element\data\domain.data
element\data\domain1.data
element\data\domain2.data
element\data\domain3.data
element\data\domain4.data
element\data\dyn_tasks.data
element\data\dynamicobjects.data
element\data\forbidden_task.txt
element\data\hometowndata
element\data\path.data
element\data\task_npc.data
element\data\tasks.data
element\data\tasks.data1
element\data\tasks.data10
element\data\tasks.data11
element\data\tasks.data12
element\data\tasks.data13
element\data\tasks.data14
element\data\tasks.data15
element\data\tasks.data16
element\data\tasks.data17
element\data\tasks.data18
element\data\tasks.data19
element\data\tasks.data2
element\data\tasks.data20
element\data\tasks.data21
element\data\tasks.data22
element\data\tasks.data23
element\data\tasks.data24
element\data\tasks.data25
element\data\tasks.data26
element\data\tasks.data27
element\data\tasks.data28
element\data\tasks.data29
element\data\tasks.data3
element\data\tasks.data30
element\data\tasks.data31
element\data\tasks.data32
element\data\tasks.data33
element\data\tasks.data34
element\data\tasks.data35
element\data\tasks.data36
element\data\tasks.data37
element\data\tasks.data38
element\data\tasks.data39
element\data\tasks.data4
element\data\tasks.data40
element\data\tasks.data41
element\data\tasks.data42
element\data\tasks.data43
element\data\tasks.data5
element\data\tasks.data6
element\data\tasks.data7
element\data\tasks.data8
element\data\tasks.data9
element\data\title_def.lua
element\data\title_def_u.lua
element\trees.pck
element\data\vipaward.data
element\reportbugs\zreportbugs.exe
element\interfaces.pck
[/normalFiles]
[FullCheckFiles]
element\interfaces.pck
element\Localize.ini
element\arcsdk.dll
element\avcodec-52.dll
element\avformat-52.dll
element\avutil-50.dll
element\bbsfiles\error.html
element\bbsfiles\extensions\extbank\bank3.dll
element\bbsfiles\extensions\extbank\bankbox.ini
element\bbsfiles\extensions\extbank\banklist.dll
element\bbsfiles\extensions\extbank\extbank.ini
element\bbsfiles\extensions\extbank\stat.ini
element\bbsfiles\extensions\extbank\stat_bankbox.ini
element\bbsfiles\extensions\extbank\up_temp.ini
element\berkelium.dll
element\berkelium.exe
element\building.pck
element\chrome.log
element\chrome_plugins_file.xml
element\coreclientsdk.dll
element\cursors\attack.ani
element\cursors\attack.cur
element\cursors\axe.ani
element\cursors\choose.ani
element\cursors\choose1.ani
element\cursors\choose2.ani
element\cursors\dig.ani
element\cursors\drag.ani
element\cursors\drag.cur
element\cursors\drag1.ani
element\cursors\fire.ani
element\cursors\flag.cur
element\cursors\gear.ani
element\cursors\geer.ani
element\cursors\hammer.ani
element\cursors\hand.cur
element\cursors\hand1.ani
element\cursors\hand2.ani
element\cursors\harvest1.ani
element\cursors\harvest2.ani
element\cursors\hook.ani
element\cursors\key.ani
element\cursors\knife.ani
element\cursors\normal.ani
element\cursors\pest1.ani
element\cursors\pest2.ani
element\cursors\pick.ani
element\cursors\pick.cur
element\cursors\plot.ani
element\cursors\plot1.ani
element\cursors\plot2.ani
element\cursors\point.ani
element\cursors\repair.cur
element\cursors\seed.ani
element\cursors\seed1.ani
element\cursors\seed2.ani
element\cursors\split.ani
element\cursors\steal1.ani
element\cursors\steal2.ani
element\cursors\talk.cur
element\cursors\unablepoint.ani
element\cursors\water1.ani
element\cursors\water2.ani
element\cursors\weed1.ani
element\cursors\weed2.ani
element\cursors\zoomin.cur
element\cursors\zoomout.cur
element\d3dx9_24.dll
element\dbghelp.dll
element\dbserver.conf
element\facedata.pck
element\font\fzl2jw.ttf
element\font\fzl2jw.ttf1
element\font\fzlbjw.ttf
element\font\fzlbjw.ttf1
element\font\fzxh1jw.ttf
element\ftdriver.dll
element\gfx.pck
element\grasses.pck
[/FullCheckFiles]
```

I have tried the following expression

`(?=[normalFiles])(.*?element(?:(?!\|).)*)(?![/normalFiles])`

to get the file names only between `[normalFiles]` and `[/normalFiles]` But it gets the ones between `[FullCheckFiles]` and `[/FullCheckFiles]` as well.

Comment: Side note: Feels like you will soon hit all time favorite question about using regex for nested structures...  If you'd use some existing format (like XML which your format is close to) or JSON you'd have much easier time parsing it...

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong notation for [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Positive lookbehind is `(?<=x)`, whilst positive lookahead is `(?=x)`. Also, `[` and `]` are used for denoting a character class in regex, so you need to escape them if they occur as literals.

```
(?<=\[normalFiles\])(.*?)(?=\[/normalFiles\])
```

**Edit**: I'm testing using the code below:

```
var match = Regex.Match(filesList, @"(?<=\[normalFiles\])(.*?)(?=\[/normalFiles\])", 
                        RegexOptions.Singleline);
if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Comment: That gave the same result. Is there any other ways to test it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(?:\[normalFiles\])((\n|.)*)(?=\[\/normalFiles\])
```

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oT2dU9)**

**Explanation :**

[image]

Comment: That is working somewhat, I would like to everything like
`element\userdata\systemsettings.ini|b3a2f10d9a7cfbbb6c6074b10b20586f|715`
I need to get just `element\userdata\systemsettings.ini` out of that.

Comment: After applying this regex , you can filter   element\\.*?\.\w+  refer : http://regex101.com/r/cZ6eJ7